# How can i build autocomplete with multiple selection in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

Can anyone let me know if there is a way to build autocomplete field with multiple selection option in Angular 4?

I see there are options in Angular 2 but i don't find any option so far with Angular 4 support.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Angular 2 code will mostly work with Angular 4. Have you tried using the same solution with Angular 4?

Comment: @SP-TY   Did you find any autocomplete field with multiselect in angular 4?